Does $f'$ have an infinite unrestricted limit at 1?
Let $f$ be an analytic function defined in the unit disc $\mathbb{D}=\{z:|z|<1\}$. If the unrestricted limit of $f$ at the boundary point $1$ equals to $\infty$, i.e.
$$
\lim_{\substack{z \rightarrow 1 \\ z\in \mathbb{D}}}f(z)=\infty,
$$
can we say $f'$, the derivative of $f$, also has an infinite unrestricted limit at the boundary point $1$?
I have already proved that for every $r\in(0,1)$, $f'$ is unbounded in the region of this form $\{z:|z-1|<r\}\cap\{z:|z|<1\}$. But I don't know whether the unrestricted limit of $f'$ at the point $1$ equals to $\infty$.
Can you give me some hints or references to this question. Thank you very much.

What if $f$ were univalent analytic in the unit disc?
